# request.form[""] cannot get value in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPostion);
        }
    }

    function getPostion(position) {
        var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var currentLon = position.coords.longitude;
        alert(currentLat);
        document.forms[0].lat.value = "123";
        alert(document.forms[0].lat.value);
        document.forms[1].lon.value = currentLon;
        alert(document.forms[1].lon.value);
    }
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="lat">
<input type="hidden" name="lon">

<asp:TextBox ID="status" runat="server" CssClass="text" MaxLength="100" Columns="40" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="textSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="textSubmit" Text="submit" OnClientClick="getLocation()" OnClick="Post" />

protected void Post(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string latitude = Request.Form["lat"].ToString();
        string longitude = Request.Form["lon"].ToString();

        string text = status.Text.Trim().ToString();//breakpoint here
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Locations] VALUES('jshmqjw'," + Convert.ToDouble(latitude) + ", " + Convert.ToDouble(longitude) + ",CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 20), 'text' )", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error reading The database. " + err.Message + "') </script>");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

[image]
i want to send variable from javascript to C#.
i use hidden field to store value first and then in C# use request.form["name"] to get the value. But after i set a breakpoint after one line, it turns out that the variables are null.
can anyone help!~

Comment: Why don't you enclose your elements in a form in html?

Comment: I don't see a `form` element - this is not valid HTML if there isn't one.

Comment: actually i'm using a master page. this is just part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

Replace your html hidden fields with:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="lat" runat="server"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="lon" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your getPosition()-

```
document.getElementById('<%= lat.ClientID %>').value= currentLat ;
document.getElementById('<%= lon.ClientID %>').value= currentLon ;
```

And in code behind:

```
string latitude = lat.Value;
string longitude = lon.Value;
```

Comment: Let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: More over what value does your position variable in `getPostion(position)` hold? Is it holding a latlng value?

Comment: that's the api of HTML5 geo-location and i'm sure it is correct. i have used several methods, trying to send data from JS to C# but failed again and again..

Comment: The above solution will work if you want passing data from JS to C#. I usually use it. If you are using the above solution and still have issues, the problem is with your getPostion() and getLocation() method.

Comment: `OnClientClick="getLocation()" OnClick="Post"`- I doubt this statement in your Button source may b the issue. Can you try creating two buttons, one having `OnClientClick="getLocation()"` being clicked first and second button with `OnClick="Post"` to be clicked next.

Comment: i just look at the <form> tag and find that "<form runat="server">" doesn't contain method or other attributes. Any problems?

Comment: You mean in properties window you donot find any methods and attributes for the form?

Comment: yeah, i get it. i create a second button and use document.getElementById("<%=test.ClientID%>").click() to click it. the button should be invisible but after i set "visible=false", it doesn't work again. how to make the click() work and at the same time the button is invisible?

Comment: Thats easy. Since you r using 2 buttons in the first button click, at the end write Button1.visible= false and Button2.visible = true. In Button2 click at end write BUtton1.visible=true and Button2.visible=false.

Comment: solved. we need to set "style='display:none'". if we write visible=false, document.click() cannot find the button. thanks a lot!~^_^

Answer (score 1):

Add runat="server":

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="lat" name="lat">
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="lon" name="lon">
```

And

```
 string latitude = lan.Value;
 string longitude = lon.Value;
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function getPostion(position) {
    var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var currentLon = position.coords.longitude;
    alert(currentLat);
    document.getElementById("<%=lan.ClientID%>").value = "123";
    alert(document.getElementById("<%=lan.ClientID%>").value);
    document.getElementById("<%=lon.ClientID%>").value = currentLon;
    alert(document.getElementById("<%=lon.ClientID%>").value);
}
```

Also, you can use:

```
<asp:HiddenField />
```

Comment: I would suggest using controls... `<asp:HiddenField ID="lat" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>`. You can also use ClientIDMode="Static" to avoid the <%=...%> syntax (requires .NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

this maybe because you put the javascript above the targeted code.

if you refer to a tag element using  "document.getElement..." then that tag element must already be rendered in order to find it.

either you put the code after you targeted elements, or use Jquery document ready.

Comment: if i set the type of "input" to "text" rather than "hidden", i can see the value when alert is executed, which means the tag can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the corresponding `name` attributes

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat">
<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon">
```